# Translate web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I tried to translate my web page using js but my code is not working here my code

```
<div class="navLan">
    <a href="" id="menu-item_en" onclick="change_language(this.id)">EN</a>
    <!-- <hr> -->
    <a href="" id="menu-item_ru" onclick="change_language(this.id)">RU</a>
    <!-- <hr> -->
    <a href="" id="menu-item_uz" onclick="change_language(this.id)">UZ</a>
</div>
```

where user select languages and i used `key` to give attr to the element like this

```
<div class="listGroup">
    <a href="#row3" class="hvr-grow nav-link lang" key='about'>About</a>
    <a href="#row4" class="nav-link lang" key="courses">Courses</a>
    <a href="#row5" class="nav-link lang" key='reg'>Registration</a>
    <a href="#row6" class="nav-link lang" key='news'>News</a>
    <a href="#row7" class="nav-link lang" key='feedback'>Feedback</a>
    <a href="#row8" class="nav-link lang" key='contact'>Contacts</a>
    <div class="hr"></div>
</div>
```

at the end of the code in script tag i gave translation like this

```
var arrLang = {
    'menu-item_en': {
        'about':'About',
        'courses':'Courses',
        'reg':'Registration',
        'news':'News',
        'feedback':'Feedback',
        'contact':'Contacts'
       },
    'menu-item_ru': {
        'about':'About',
        'courses':'Courses',
        'reg':'Registration',
        'news':'News',
        'feedback':'Feedback',
        'contact':'Contacts'
      },
    'menu-item_uz': {
        'about':'Biz Haqimizda',
        'courses':'Kurslar',
        'reg':'Ro\'yxatdan o\'tmoq',
        'news':'Yangiliklar',
        'feedback':'Fikr-Mulohaza',
        'contact':'Aloqa'
      }
   }
```

finally my js file here

```
function change_language(id) {
  var lang = id;
  document.cookie = "lang=" + lang + ";";

  var elementss = document.getElementsByClassName('lang');
  var placeholders = document.getElementsByClassName('placeholders');

  if (document.cookie.split(';').filter(function (item) {
    return item.indexOf('lang=menu-item_en') >= 0
  }).length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elementss.length; i++) {
        elementss[i].innerHTML = arrLang['menu-item_en'][elementss[i].getAttribute('key')];
    }
    for (let g = 0; g < placeholders.length; g++){
        placeholders[g].setAttribute('placeholder', arrLang['menu-item_en'][placeholders[g].getAttribute('key')]);
    }
  } else if (document.cookie.split(';').filter(function (item) {
    return item.indexOf('lang=menu-item_uz') >= 0
}).length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elementss.length; i++) {
        elementss[i].innerHTML = arrLang['menu-item_uz'][elementss[i].getAttribute('key')];
    }
    for (let g = 0; g < placeholders.length; g++){
        placeholders[g].setAttribute('placeholder', arrLang['menu-item_uz'][placeholders[g].getAttribute('key')]);
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < elementss.length; i++) {
        elementss[i].innerHTML = arrLang['menu-item_ru'][elementss[i].getAttribute('key')];
    }
    for (let g = 0; g < placeholders.length; g++){
        placeholders[g].setAttribute('placeholder', arrLang['menu-item_ru'][placeholders[g].getAttribute('key')]);
    }
  }
};

(function () {
    var elementss = document.getElementsByClassName('lang');
    var placeholders = document.getElementsByClassName('placeholders');
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputs');

  if (document.cookie.split(';').filter(function (item) {
    return item.indexOf('lang=menu-item_en') >= 0
  }).length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elementss.length; i++) {
        elementss[i].innerHTML = arrLang['menu-item_en'][elementss[i].getAttribute('key')];
    }
    for (let g = 0; g < placeholders.length; g++){
        placeholders[g].setAttribute('placeholder', arrLang['menu-item_en'][placeholders[g].getAttribute('key')]);
    } 
    for (let j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++){
        inputs[j].setAttribute('value', arrLang['menu-item_en'][inputs[j].getAttribute('key')]);
    } 
  } else if (document.cookie.split(';').filter(function (item) {
    return item.indexOf('lang=menu-item_uz') >= 0
  }).length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elementss.length; i++) {
        elementss[i].innerHTML = arrLang['menu-item_uz'][elementss[i].getAttribute('key')];
    }
    for (let g = 0; g < placeholders.length; g++){
        placeholders[g].setAttribute('placeholder', arrLang['menu-item_uz'][placeholders[g].getAttribute('key')]);
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++){
        inputs[j].setAttribute('value', arrLang['menu-item_uz'][inputs[j].getAttribute('key')]);
    } 
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < elementss.length; i++) {
        elementss[i].innerHTML = arrLang['menu-item_ru'][elementss[i].getAttribute('key')];
    }
    for (let g = 0; g < placeholders.length; g++){
        placeholders[g].setAttribute('placeholder', arrLang['menu-item_ru'][placeholders[g].getAttribute('key')]);
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++){
        inputs[j].setAttribute('value', arrLang['menu-item_ru'][inputs[j].getAttribute('key')]);
    } 
  }
})();
```

anyone can correct me please?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when HTML is rendering you probably don't have `change_language` function, so `onclick="change_language(this.id)"` binds anything to `onclick`. Let's try to add `addEventListener` using javascript.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jugrae2z/

Comment: yes in your example it is working but if i add to my code it is not working. As well as queryselector('a') is not work for another code right I mean "p" or other elements? because I showed piece of my code